# Anyone Remember a Short Story or Novel about Cosmic Balance in the SF Bay Area?

Tags: story-identification, books, horror

I read a novel (or possibly short story) years ago about a sort-of "cosmic balance" in the San Francisco Bay area. I recall the cover (or illustration) depicting a giant old-fashioned scale superimposed over the bay area, though that could be my imagination over time.

I believe it was by one of the writers in the Cthulhu Mythos world, possibly Derleth, Ashton Smith, Bloch, Long, or the like, though I don't think the story itself was really of the mythos, though there was definitely a feeling of foreboding and, iirc, a certain sense of hopelessness on the part of the protagonist.

I've scanned through the bibliographies of the likely culprits but no title jumps out and Google is no help.

Comment: South Bay or North Bay? If it was Marin County, that would probably be [Dick](http://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/ea.cgi?Philip_K._Dick), but I don't recognize the story. More details about the story would help. Were there actual scales in the story? When is “years ago”?

Comment: To help make "story-identification" questions more useful, I'll note that while I wasn't able to remember a lot of details, I found the book to be utterly fascinating. The descriptions of how one can *feel* the balances, stressors, and energy of a city really rang true for me. I look forward to re-reading this excellent story.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It sounds like it could be Fritz Leiber's *Our Lady of Darkness*. The book is about, in part, the fictional  pseudoscience of megapolisomancy, which was developed by fictional occultist Thibaut de Castries, an associate of Clark Ashton Smith's. The Wikipedia entry [sez](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Our_Lady_of_Darkness)

> According to De Castries, excessively large cities pose a clear danger to the people living in and near them by allowing mass quantities of certain substances (city-stuff) to accumulate, which in turn draw the attention of paramental forces. Through the manipulation of the paramental forces, a megapolisomancer could predict and alter the future.

Comment: Bingo, thanks! The Wikipedia entry also includes mention of the San Francisco part: "The book is set in San Francisco, California, and the city and some of its buildings are integral to the story-line. In particular, Corona Heights, the Sutro Tower, the Hobart Building, the Trans-America Pyramid and 811 Geary are critical story-elements. Though the book was published in 1978, many of these elements remain."